# Program acts weird

Tags: java

trying to make program where after clicking on buttom it should open new JFrame inside it should have different labels and TextFields....It all compile and work how it should beside History JTextField and hisScrollPAne these ScrollPAne not appeared at all TextField Appeared in completly wrong place....if change bounds armor JTextField and historyJTextField then it history appearing in right place but armor in wrong..not sure what I did wrong.....dimenssions of JFrame(800,900)
This is whole code related to this JFrame...

private void object704JButtonActonPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

```
    JFrame object704  = new JFrame("object704");
    object704.setLayout(new BorderLayout());



        JLabel titleJLabel704 = new JLabel();
        titleJLabel704.setBounds(0,20,800,36);
        titleJLabel704.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        titleJLabel704.setText("Object704");
        titleJLabel704.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        object704.add(titleJLabel704);

        JLabel obPicJLabel = new JLabel();
        obPicJLabel.setBounds(190,90,400,215);
        obPicJLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gr/objPic.jpg"));
        object704.add(obPicJLabel);

        JLabel weaponJLabel = new JLabel();
        weaponJLabel.setBounds(113,345,70,30);
        weaponJLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,20));
        weaponJLabel.setText("Weapon");
        object704.add(weaponJLabel);

        JLabel armorJLabel = new JLabel();
        armorJLabel.setBounds(345,345,70,30);
        armorJLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,20));
        armorJLabel.setText("Armor");
        object704.add(armorJLabel);

        JLabel historyJLabel = new JLabel();
        historyJLabel.setBounds(590,345,70,30);
        historyJLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,20));
        historyJLabel.setText("History");
        object704.add(historyJLabel);

        JTextArea weaponJTextArea = new JTextArea("Test2");
        weaponJTextArea.setEditable(false);
        weaponJTextArea.setBounds(40,380,225,400);
        object704.add(weaponJTextArea);

        JScrollPane scrollJScrollPane = new JScrollPane(weaponJTextArea);
        scrollJScrollPane.setBounds(40,380,225,400);
        object704.add(scrollJScrollPane);

        JTextArea armorJTextArea = new JTextArea("Test1");
        //armorJTextArea.setEditable(false);
        armorJTextArea.setVerticalAlignment(JTextArea.CENTER);
        armorJTextArea.setBounds(287,380,225,400);  
        object704.add(armorJTextArea);  

        JScrollPane armScrollPane = new JScrollPane(armorJTextArea);
        armScrollPane.setBounds(287,380,225,400);
        object704.add(armScrollPane);

        JTextField historyJtextField = new JTextField("test");
        //historyJtextField.setEditable(false);
        historyJtextField.setBounds(530,380,200,400);
        object704.add(historyJtextField);


        JTextArea historyJTextArea = new JTextArea();
        historyJTextArea.setEditable(false);
        historyJTextArea.setBounds(530,380,200,400);
        object704.add(historyJTextArea);

        JScrollPane hisScrollPane = new JScrollPane(historyJTextArea);
        hisScrollPane.setBounds(530,380,200,400);
        object704.add(hisScrollPane);


        object704.setSize(850,900);
        object704.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: what is the layout manager you are using for this application.

Comment: I used BorderLayout...if use Flow....then it completle messed up....

Comment: When you use a LayoutManager, you should not have to call `setBounds` at all. Apart from that, you are adding the elements to TWO containers (e.g. `weaponJTextArea` is added to "object704" and to the "scrollJScrollPane" (horrible names, BTW). And it sounds as if the call to `frame.setVisible(true)` was NOT the last call of your GUI creation code, as it should be.

Comment: please put your complete code and then we will be able to help you.

Comment: Marco I had to add this to two containers because it didn't show up square around my JTextArea....so I know it looks kind of messy now but thats only one way how I were able to make GUI looks almost how it should.....maybe I'm lamer but I'm just learning)